# Mod_rewrite in two directions?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

An existing page is called `/foo/bar.php`. What I have done is a rewrite so that when a user types `/foobar`, it load the contents of `/foo/bar.php` (while keeping `/foobar` in the url bar)

But I also want the opposite - when a user clicks on a link or types `/foo/bar.php`, I want to have `/foobar` in the url. The reason is to avoid manually changing all the links.

How could I do that (if possible without an http redirect, but via some rewrite magic)? And is it possible for those two rules to co-exist?

**Edit** - After the first response, I realized my description of the problem was not proper. `/foobar` is not supposed to be a concatenation of `foo`, `bar` of `/foo/bar.php`, but an arbitrary string (`/whatever`).

**Edit 2:**

I now added `RewriteRule ^whetever/?$ /foo/bar.php [L]` in the `/ .htaccess`. Then I added `RewriteRule bar\.php$ /whetever [R=302,L]` in the `/foo .htaccess`. The problem is it 's a circular reference and fails.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo/[^/]+\.php$
RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} !true
RewriteRule ^/foo/([^/]+)\.php$ /foo$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo[^/]
RewriteRule ^/foo(.*) /foo/$1.php [L]
```

The first part matches `/foo/something.php` and transforms them into `/foosomething`, but **only if it is not a sub-request**.

The second part takes any `/foosometing` and transforms it into `/foo/something.php`, via **sub-request**

Comment: When I put those in a blank htaccess my rewrite logs say `%{IS_SUBREQ}` is always false, even if the request was `/foosomething`. And loops internally.

Answer (score 0):

You can try matching against `%{THE_REQUEST}` and only do the redirect when the actual request is for the php file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /foo/bar\.php
RewriteRule bar\.php$ /whatever [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^whatever/?$ /foo/bar.php [L]
```